# Testing method with no output

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following method I want to test:

```
class SomeObject {
   public function actionFromSomeController() {
       $obj = new OtherObject();
       $obj -> setAttributes();
       $obj -> doAction();
   }
}

class OtherObject {
   private $_attr;
   public function setAttributes() {
      $this -> _attr = 'something';
      Database :: execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES (' . $this -> _attr . ')');
      $fileObj = new FileObj();
      $content = $fileObj -> getSomeFileContent();
      // do something else
   }
   public function doAction() {
      echo $this -> _attr;
   }
}
```

Now I want to test this method, its output depends on database content and one file on the server. It does a lot of things on the way, and the output is just one ID and `success => 1`.

How should I test it properly?

Comment: maybe creating a manual example data, in format that you expect from the db or the file...

Comment: Your current architecture makes testing difficult. If you *do* manage to setup a test for it, you can test the return value (an array, in this case)

Comment: Hey @Janusz Kowalski - just wondering whether one of the comments or my answer was of any help to you or you need any further assistance on this or a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas on how to test small code pieces like this:

- Generate test-data and pass it to your methods (also, fake database return data or file contents)
- Use `echo` / `var_dump()` / `die()` to check property and variable content at different positions in your methods
- Also use these commands to check whether execution reaches a certain point (for example to see whether a function got called or not)
- If something doesn't work as expected without an error message: Check line by line with the above methods until you find the problem
- Consider using **interfaces** and **dependency injection** if your code gets bigger - this is a bit over-the-top for this amount of code, but can be a tremendous time-saver when your application becomes big

Testing is never an automatic process and you will always have to think about what makes sense to do and what not. These things to do are never magic but basic PHP.

You should consider letting your scripts throw errors/exceptions if something goes wrong. Writing "silent" applications is almost never good since you can, if you really need a silent execution for production environments, just turn off error reporting and have the same effect. Many PHP functions return something special on failure and/or success and you can check for this. Database handlers do so, too. Do yourself a favor and use these return values!